# Shell: How to append a prefix while looping through an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm trying to loop through an array and append a prefix to each value in the array. Simplified version of the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
databases=( db1 db2 db3 )
for i in live_${databases[@]} stage_${databases[@]}
do
    ....
done
```

However, it only prepends the prefix to the first value in the array - the values it loops through are:

```
live_db1 db2 db3 stage_db1 db2 db3
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: ( "prepend" for prefix; "append" would make sense for a suffix ;-) )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
databases=( db1 db2 db3 )
for i in ${databases[@]/#/live_} ${databases[@]/#/stage_}
do
    ....
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
databases="db1 db2 db3"
for i in $databases
do
    x="live_$i"
    y="stage_$i"
    echo "$x $y"
done
```

Comment: I would prefer to have the prefix appended in the `for` line. The reason is that I have a 3rd array to loop through as well, which does not take a prefix. (`for i in $core live_$dbs stage_$dbs`). Thank you though - maybe strings would be a better alternative to arrays.

Comment: Well, I was able to figure out a solution. I added a separate for loop through $databases appending `live_$i stage_$i` to $core and then modified the main for loop to only go through $core. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $( for d in ${databases[@]}; do echo "live_$d stage_$d"; done )
do
    ....
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to *John Kugelman*'s answer. Details can be found in:

*bash man page -> Parameter Expansion -> Pattern substitution*

> ...
>   If pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the
>   expanded value of parameter.
>   ...